# How can I consume wcf service for login in Native apps with Portable class library (PCL) in xamarin studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, xamarin

**How can I consume wcf service for login in Native apps with Portable class library (PCL) in xamarin studio.**

I have already created WCF Services for Login and hosted on IIS.

Now i want use this wcf service in **xamarin studio Native application with Portable Class Library (PCL)** for login, change password and forget password.

I have created Android, ios and Window Phone 8.0 Project in visual studio solution.

I have make so much RND on this but  I couldn't find any proper way.

Comment: Are you asking how to send/receive data to/from webservice?

Comment: @DushyantBangal  Yes.

Comment: You asked the same questions 3 times!

Comment: Answered Here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826467/visual-studio-2015-xamarin-native-portable-pcl-wcf/36826468#36826468

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

// A POST request needs HttpContent along with the webservice URI
string body = "YOUR REQUEST BODY HERE"; // username/password in JSON format
var content = new StringContent(body);

client.PostAsync("YOUR_SERVICE_URL", content);
```

If your webservice needs some headers, use:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key","value");
```

You can also send the username/password as headers.

**NOTE: You might need to add `Microsoft.net.Http` package from nuget**

Comment: I am talking about Xamarin Native apps using portable library. it is not working in PCL.

Comment: I just tried a GET request in Native Portable. Its working.
I dont think it matters if its Native or Forms application, the code in this case remains the same!

You're doing something wrong if its not working, you should post what exactly is happening.